# Matching up / merging rows together in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I am converting an xml document into a dataframe for my work using the following method:

```
p = XMLParser(huge_tree=True)
tree = parse('Epidemeology - Orphadata.xml', parser=p)
root = tree.getroot()

Orpha_Code = []
Orpha_Prevalence = []
Orpha_Geography = []
Orpha_Prevalence_Type = []

for child in root.findall('Disorder'):
    Orphacode = child.find('OrphaCode')
    Orpha_Code.append(Orphacode.text)

    #Epidemeology Data - finding nested xml text:

    for node in child.findall('.//Prevalence'):
        for snode in node.find('PrevalenceType'):
            Orpha_Prevalence_Type.append(snode.text)
        for snode_geography in node.find('PrevalenceGeographic'):
            Orpha_Geography.append(snode_geography.text)
        for snode_prevalence in node.find('PrevalenceClass'):
            Orpha_Prevalence.append(snode_prevalence.text)



a = {'OrphaCode': Orpha_Code, 'Prevalence Type': Orpha_Prevalence_Type, 'Prevalence Geography': Orpha_Geography, 'Prevalence': Orpha_Prevalence}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df_transpose = df.transpose()
```

Each 'OrphaCode' corresponds to an identity, of which there is one per entry. However, for the prevalence, there can be multiple variables (2 - 10) for each one identity/entry.

When I convert all this information to a dataframe, the ID's then no longer match up with the prevalence information, as the ID's are printed one on each row while the prevalence information for each ID can go over multiple rows. I end up with loads of blank rows at the bottom.

Is there a way of automatically matching them up so there is blank space in between or another alternative way of making sure the ID and prevalence information match up?

I would do this manually but there are close to 6,000 ID entries.

Sorry if this is really convoluted, I am terrible at explaining things. I have been stuck on this for hours and any help would be really appreciated!

**Edit**

A snapshot of the XML data is provided below:

```
<DisorderList count="6042">
    <Disorder id="17601">
      <OrphaCode>166024</OrphaCode>
      <ExpertLink lang="en">http://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/OC_Exp.php?lng=en&amp;Expert=166024</ExpertLink>
      <Name lang="en">Multiple epiphyseal dysplasia, Al-Gazali type</Name>
      <DisorderType id="21394">
        <Name lang="en">Disease</Name>
      </DisorderType>
      <DisorderGroup id="36547">
        <Name lang="en">Disorder</Name>
      </DisorderGroup>
      <PrevalenceList count="2">
        <Prevalence id="8322">
          <Source>11389160[PMID]_9689990[PMID]_ [EXPERT]</Source>
          <PrevalenceType id="23697">
            <Name lang="en">Cases/families</Name>
          </PrevalenceType>
          <PrevalenceQualification id="23718">
            <Name lang="en">Case</Name>
          </PrevalenceQualification>
          <PrevalenceClass/>
          <ValMoy>4.0</ValMoy>
          <PrevalenceGeographic id="23844">
            <Name lang="en">Worldwide</Name>
          </PrevalenceGeographic>
          <PrevalenceValidationStatus id="25958">
            <Name lang="en">Validated</Name>
          </PrevalenceValidationStatus>
        </Prevalence>
```

The prevalence list count provides the number of prevalence entries - it can range from 2 - 10. The OrphaCode is the identifier and is one per entire entry (there can be several prevalence entries for one OrphaCode entry).

The multiple v single entries causes the overall structure of the dataframe to become out of alignment as the identifier codes don't match up with the prevalence entries. Is there a way of adding blank space automatically or perhaps appending the dataframe during the for loop to avoid the error? Below is the output to highlight what I mean.

```
      OrphaCode   Prevalence Type Prevalence Geography       Prevalence
0        166024    Cases/families            Worldwide   <1 / 1 000 000
1            58  Point prevalence            Worldwide   <1 / 1 000 000
2        166032  Annual incidence                Japan          Unknown
3            61  Point prevalence            Worldwide   <1 / 1 000 000
4        166029    Cases/families            Worldwide  1-9 / 1 000 000
...         ...               ...                  ...              ...
15431      None  Point prevalence            Worldwide             None
15432      None  Point prevalence               Europe             None
15433      None  Point prevalence            Worldwide             None
15434      None    Cases/families            Worldwide             None
15435      None  Point prevalence            Worldwide             None
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. Please add a sample of your data and any errors/output to your question which will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful for you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks DaveL17, hopefully my edit has made it a bit clearer